# Knapsack prob, but allow over-filling

Tags: python, knapsack-problem

Lets say I have 5 items (name, size, value) as follows:

```
("ITEM01", 100, 10000)
("ITEM02", 24, 576)
("ITEM03", 24, 576)
("ITEM04", 51, 2500)
("ITEM05", 155, 25)
```

and I have to get the closest match to a total size of 150 (each item can only be added once).

This is very similar to the knapsack problem, but not quite since in this case my preferable solution would be `ITEM01`, `ITEM04` giving a total size of 151 (the knapsack problem would stop me going over size = 150 and hence give `ITEM01`, `ITEM02` and `ITEM03` with a total size of 148).

Does this problem have a name? (Is it still `combinatorial optimisation`)? I'm looking for a python solution, but it would help if I knew the name of what I am looking for.

Comment: The knapsack problem is to maximize value while maintaining the condition total weight <= capacity. Try to specify your constraints more formally (like maximize value with |capacity - total weight| <= delta for some delta, or maximize value - cost * (|capacity - total weight|).

Comment: How does item value feature in your objective function?

Comment: @jakber I'm looking for the (best value) combination that gives me a size nearest to the total size. But unlike the knapsack, it can go over the total size.

Comment: @NPE size is most important - aiming to get closest (+/-) to the total size of 150. After that value is to be maximised (ie if you had a case where two combinations were equally close to 150, you would choose the higher value combination).

Comment: @jakber I think his constraint here is   min(|total_weight-capacity|)

Comment: If you're not concerned about the weight at all - just pick the greedy approach (calculate value/weight, than pick one item a time until you satisfied). If you are somewhat concerned about weight - it looks like you can set the penalty for overweight and again, pick the greedy approach.

Comment: @J0HN I am concerned about the weight (or in this case size). It needs to be as close as possible to the total size, so the penalty for overweight method might work. Would you still consider this a knapsack problem though or should I be looking for something under another name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do it using dynamic programming.

Let `dp[k]` be equal to a list of items, with the sum of size equal to `k`. Initially `d[0] = []` and `dp[k] = None` for `k > 0`. The size of the list may be bounded by the sum of sizes of all elements, let's call it `S`.

What the algorithm does is for each `item` it goes from `i = S` down to `i = 0` and it checks if `dp[i] != None`, which means we know we are able to select items with sum of sizes equal to `i`. These items are on the list `dp[i]`. Let's observe that we can add the current `item` to that list and have a set of items with sum equal to `i + item.size`. So we assign `dp[i + item.size] = dp[i] + [item]`. Having processed all items we just have to start at the desired sum of sizes and go both directions to find the closest match.

Code:

```
items = [("ITEM01", 100, 10000), ("ITEM02", 24, 576), \
    ("ITEM03", 24, 576), ("ITEM04", 51, 2500), ("ITEM05", 155, 25)]
S = sum([item[1] for item in items])
dp = [None for i in xrange(S + 1)]
dp[0] = []

for item in items:
    for i in xrange(S, -1, -1):
        if dp[i] is not None and i + item[1] <= S:
            dp[i + item[1]] = dp[i] + [item]

desired_sum = 150
i = j = desired_sum

while i >= 0 and j <= S:
    if dp[i] is not None:
        print dp[i]
        break
    elif dp[j] is not None:
        print dp[j]
        break
    else:
        i -= 1
        j += 1
```

output:

```
[('ITEM01', 100, 10000), ('ITEM04', 51, 2500)]
```

However the complexity of this solution is `O(n*S)` where `n` is the number of items and `S` is the sum of sizes, so it may be too slow for some purposes. What can be improved in this solution is the `S` constant. For example you can set `S` to `2 * desired_sum` because we have guarantee that we can take a set of items with sum of sizes in `[0, 2 * desired_sum]` (possibly an empty set with sum `0`). If you want to take at least one item you can take `S = max(min_item_size, 2 * desired_sum - min_item_size)` where `min_item_size` is the minimum of sizes of all items.

**EDIT**:

Oh, you also wanted get maximise value when two combinations are equally close to `desired_size`. Then you have to alternate the code a bit to keep the best combinations for each sum of sizes.

Namely:

```
if dp[i] is not None and i + item[1] <= S:
```

should be:

```
if dp[i] is not None and i + item[1] <= S and \
    (
        dp[i + item[1]] is None
        or
        sum(set_item[2] for set_item in dp[i]) + item[2]
            > sum(set_item[2] for set_item in dp[i + item[1]])
    ):
```

(a bit ugly, but I don't know how to break lines to make it look better)

Of course you can keep these sums to avoid calculating them each time.

Comment: Many thanks. Yes this works very nicely as far as I can tell so far (with the edit). It may slow down on some of the bigger numbers I might have to throw at it, but for the minute it seems good.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a working knapsack-solver and a lot of time:

Set value of each item to the weight of each item and solve the knapsack problem with capacity 150. This will give you the maximum size smaller than the target (148 in your example). So the maximum size to consider is 150 + (150 - 148) = 152

Now solve it again for each integer between 150 and 152. If you find a smaller difference (151 in your example) stop, use that and solve for value using the original item values. If the range is big you could also try binary search.

Otherwise solve the original knapsack problem with capacity 148 and 152 and pick the solution with the greatest value.

Comment: Yes this works too (shame I cannot accept two answers) and I had developed something very similar. Using the working knapsack-solver, I run it once to a max size of my ideal size *1.1 so I can accept values 10% over the size. I then find the best solution for the ideal size. After that I iterate through increasing the max size from the ideal size upwards until I find one. I can then compare the two before making a final choice.

Many thanks for the input.