# Knapsack problem with repeating components for lowest value, to fill (or slightly over) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, knapsack-problem

I'm actually trying to find the lowest cost to supply custom medication doses from vials - however while researching, I found the knapsack problem is the best way to describe the issue, in  way that is currently understood.

Breakdown of problem
*A dose is prescribed based on clinical need.
*The vials commercially available to make up the dose (and their respective dose) are then considered. The same size vial can be used more than once.
*The vial / size combination may provide excess (i.e. provide a higher dose than is required) - as that combination works out cheaper than meeting the dose itself, or providing a smaller overage. Therefore overage or wastage is allowed provided the combinations yields the prescribed dose, even if there is wastage.
*The output should display the qty/ vial combination used and the cost of that combinations.

Example of vials available are 50mg costs $15, 100mg costs $32 and 200mg costs $64

Lets say that a dose of 220mg is prescribed. Some of the possible options to make up the dose are as follows (remembering that the amount of wastage is not relevant provided it provides the cheapest option to make up the dose required.

```
5 x 50mg = 250mg (30mg over) = $75
3 x 50mg + 1 x 100mg = 250mg (30mg over) = $77
2 x 100mg + 1 x 200mg = 400mg (180mg over) = $128
1 x 50mg + 1 x 200mg = 250mg (30mg over) = $79
3 x 100mg = 300mg (80mg over) = $96
```

Therefore, we can see that the cheapest option is row1 5x 50mg at $75

If anyone could point me in the right direction then I'd be grateful!

The code below only uses each component once - but I'm lost on how to modify to get it to recycle them.

```
items = [("ITEM01", 100, 10000), ("ITEM02", 24, 576), \
    ("ITEM03", 24, 576), ("ITEM04", 51, 2500), ("ITEM05", 155, 25)]
S = sum([item[1] for item in items])    #sums all the weights in the list of items
dp = [None for i in range(S + 1)]       #list within which cycles through each integer of weights creates a list of "None,"
dp[0] = []                              #removes the first none from the list

for item in items:                      #for each element in the list of available vials
    for i in range(S, -1, -1):          #counts down from sum of all weights of available vial sizes DOWN TO zero (0) 
        if dp[i] is not None and i + item[1] <= S and \     
    (                                                               #if the long list of Nones - does not read None
        dp[i + item[1]] is None
        or
        sum(set_item[2] for set_item in dp[i]) + item[2]
            > sum(set_item[2] for set_item in dp[i + item[1]])
    ):
            dp[i + item[1]] = dp[i] + [item]

desired_sum = 200                   #desired weight 
i = j = desired_sum                 # desired sum becomes i and it also becomes j

while i >= 0 and j <= S:            #while desired sum(i) is over 0 and less then sum of weight of all vials in the list.
    if dp[i] is not None:           #if the none list entry at that point is NOT none
        print (dp[i])               #print element from that list that isn't 'None'
        break
    elif dp[j] is not None:         #if None list at desired_weight index is not None
        print (dp[j])               #print the element that isn't none
        break
    else:
        i -= 1                      #else diverge i and j which are originally the same
        j += 1
```

Comment: In your example I would assume that the 50mg dose always wins as it is always the cheapest. Imagine a dose of 100, 2x15$ is less than 1x100mg. Right now I cannot see any dose where choosing anything else than the 50mg vials.

Comment: I'd assume that you need some additional constraint here, e.g. the maximum number of vials spent for each patient is three or something like this.

Comment: Uwe - yes that's correct. 5x 50mg would win (in this case). I have to run this scenarios for 27 different medications, some of which have up to 5 vial size combinations. There is no maximum number of vials that can be used per dose - it's purely based on minimum cost (despite wastage)!

Comment: In your 27 scenarios, have you found one where the 50mg vials do not win?

Comment: Those were just round numbers for the sake of simplicity. I have over 4000 rows of transactions to look at - and those 4000 rows are made up of 27 different drugs. Each drug has different number/ size of vials available and different prices. The price is not always as linear as the example provided. Below, the cost per mg is linear aside from the smallest vial, which is 6cents more. per mg
`5000 $471.05 (cost per mg = 0.09)
1000 $94.21 (cost per mg = 0.09)
500 $47.11 (cost per mg = 0.09)
50 $4.71 (cost per mg = 0.09)
5 $4.82 (cost per mg = 0.096)`

Comment: I'd try to work something out with the greedy algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm

Comment: Did you take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501558/knapsack-prob-but-allow-over-filling)?

Comment: Thank you @Gerd - this problem looks very similar! Much appreciated

Comment: Thanks @UweZiegenhagen - I'll have  good read - but on first glance it looks like it's going to offer the theory for this problem. Appreciate your responses.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501558/knapsack-prob-but-allow-over-filling?noredirect=1&lq=1 this "allow overfilling" should be similar to your challenge.

Comment: Also check https://skerritt.blog/dynamic-programming/ it seems to give a really nice overview